# python loop list index out of range

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

i can't see it.
why my loop is not well !?
**please try to help me :)**

```html
def sort_anagrams(list_of_strings):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(list_of_strings)):
        deleted_items = 0
        templist = []
        templist.append(list_of_strings[i])
        for j in range(i+1, len(list_of_strings) - deleted_items):
            print("*debug: i=", i, "j=", j, "len-list=", len(list_of_strings), "del-items=", deleted_items, "len-del=", len(list_of_strings) - deleted_items, "j-del = ", j-deleted_items)
            if sorted(list(list_of_strings[i])) == sorted(list(list_of_strings[j - deleted_items])):
                templist.append(list_of_strings[j - deleted_items])
                print("~joined!", templist)
                list_of_strings.remove(list_of_strings[j - deleted_items])
                deleted_items += 1
        result.append(templist)
    print(result)
    return result


list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']
print(sort_anagrams(list_of_words))

#result:
#[['deltas', 'desalt', 'slated', 'salted', 'staled', 'lasted'], ['retainers', 'ternaries'], ['pants'], ['generating', 'greatening'], ['smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts']]
```

the code should return a new list of list's that contain the original worlds from list_of_words,
grouped by anagrams (word's with the same letters)

Comment: Probably because of this line: `list_of_strings.remove(list_of_strings[j - deleted_items]) ` When you remove items your list gets shorter and i,j will probably go out of range at some point.
You would better create a copy of your original list (let's say list2) and work on list2 (removal of items, etc) while looping to your original list

Comment: StackOverlow is not a free debugging service.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guy's,
dynamic loop is just can't be crated with a for loop..

But? it working perfect with a while loop :)
Thanks a lot!

```
def sort_anagrams(list_of_strings):
result = []
while list_of_strings:
    current_word = list_of_strings[0]
    temp_list = []
    rest_list = []
    for j in list_of_strings:
        if sorted(list(current_word)) == sorted(list(j)):
            temp_list.append(j)
        else:
            rest_list.append(j)
    result.append(temp_list)
    list_of_strings = rest_list
return result


list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']
print(sort_anagrams(list_of_words))

#result:
print([['deltas', 'desalt', 'slated', 'salted', 'staled', 'lasted'], ['retainers', 'ternaries'], ['pants'], ['generating', 'greatening'], ['smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts']])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(list_of_strings)):
```

Now you determined how many `i` you will have. It is determined at this moment because `len(list_of_strings)` gives you number, not reference to list lenght.

```
       list_of_strings.remove(list_of_strings[j - deleted_items])
```

Now you deleted something from the list, so at the end your list is shorter than starting `len(list_of_strings)`.
When `i` is bigger then current length of list python will raise `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Try to loop over elements of list with:

```
for element in my_list:
     do_something
```

Comment: tried 'for element in my_list' 
now the index is well but if element removed when found anagrams, 
it still running about it for nothing..

`result:
[['deltas', 'desalt', 'slated', 'salted', 'staled', 'lasted'], ['retainers', 'ternaries'], [], ['pants'], [], ['generating', 'greatening'], [], ['smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts'], [], [], [], [], [], []]`

***now i can see it: i looking for some 'dynamic for loop'.***